# Combine Excel Text with Max Function

Tags: excel, string, function, max, concatenation

Let's suppose `A2="A1"` and `A3="A10"`. If I wanted to use the concatenate function in a max formula to find the max between the range `A1:A10`, I would write `=MAX(CONCATENATE(A2):CONCATENATE(A3))` but it fails.

Is there a way to input string in the max function? It would be useful for the task at hand.

Comment: did you try the `indirect` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `INDIRECT()`:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(A2&":"&A3))
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce! This accomplishes the task.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

`=max(indirect(A2&":"&A3),true)`

Edit:

it should have been 
`=max(indirect(A2&":"&A3,true))`

Comment: You should have suggested an edit. actually, the default value is `true` so no need to specify, but i put it in there to be clear. :)

Comment: I mistyped. Please see edit. You could have been direct to the point. LOL. Thanks for pointing out though. Someone would have been misled.